# In a chef loop over a hash, execute resource interpolates the last entry instead of current entry

Tags: chef-infra

I have written a recipe to create multiple logical volumes as part of setup for installing an application. I have a hash in the recipe that I've created by reading a JSON file which has all the metadata for the drives.

The recipe loops over this hash and is supposed to first create a logical volume and then execute a tune2fs command, immediately.

Now assume we're in the first iteration of the loop. It creates the logical volume just fine, for the first entry in the hash (lv_u01) but then when it notifies the execute block (in side the same loop, immediately), it somehow interpolates the key/values from the last entry in the hash (lv_u03). I have tried multiple times and it keeps doing the same thing. I searched and couldn't find any relevant information on why it's doing this. Is it something do with the timers? I want to run the tune2fs command right after it creates the logical volume, as later in the loop I mount the volume, and this steps needs to happen before the other steps run. Which is why I used immediately.

Can someone please help me understand what am I doing wrong here.

Here's the error that I see:

```
* lvm_logical_volume[lv_u01] action create

* execute[Run tune2fs] action run

================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[Run tune2fs]'
================================================================================

           Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
           ------------------------------------
           Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
           ---- Begin output of tune2fs -i 0 -c 0 /dev/my_vg/lv_u03 ----
           STDOUT: tune2fs 1.45.4 (23-Sep-2019)
           STDERR: tune2fs: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/my_vg/lv_u03
           Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
           ---- End output of tune2fs -i 0 -c 0 /dev/my_vg/lv_u03 ----
           Ran tune2fs -i 0 -c 0 /dev/my_vg/lv_u03 returned 1

           Resource Declaration:
           ---------------------
           # In /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/cookbook_name/recipes/recipe.rb

            88:     execute 'Run tune2fs' do
            89:         command "tune2fs -i 0 -c 0 /dev/#{val_hash['vg_name']}/#{lv_name}"
            90:         action :nothing
            91:     end
            92:

           Compiled Resource:
           ------------------
           # Declared in /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/cookbook_name/recipes/recipe.rb:88:in `block in from_file'

           execute("Run tune2fs") do
             action [:nothing]
             default_guard_interpreter :execute
             command "tune2fs -i 0 -c 0 /dev/my_vg/lv_u03"
             backup 5
             declared_type :execute
             cookbook_name "cookbook_name"
             recipe_name "recipe_name"
             domain nil
             user nil
           end

           System Info:
           ------------
           chef_version=14.14.25
           platform=centos
           platform_version=8.2.2004
           ruby=ruby 2.5.7p206 (2019-10-01 revision 67816) [x86_64-linux]
           program_name=/bin/chef-client
           executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client
```

Here's the code:

recipe.rb

```
# Read metadata about drives into a hash
require 'json'
json_file = File.open 'lv_metadata.json'
lv_hash = JSON.load json_file
json_file.close

# Create and format logical volumes.  
    lv_hash.each do |lv_name, val_hash|

        # This resource will create the logical volume based on the parameters available in lv_hash and then format it
        # If sizing is static, use the fixed value else use 100% of the free space
        lvm_logical_volume lv_name do
            group val_hash['vg_name']
            size lazy {val_hash['sizing'] == 'static' ? "#{val_hash['disk_sizes'][app_env][vm_size]}G" : "100%FREE"}
            filesystem 'ext3'
            filesystem_params lazy {lv_name == 'lv_u02' ? "-m 0 -b #{val_hash['block_size']} -J size=256" : "-m 0 -b #{val_hash['block_size']}"}
            notifies :run, "execute[Run tune2fs]", :immediately
        end

        # Runs tune2fs to disable time-dependent checking. 
        # When setting max-mount-count to 0, the number of times the filesystem is mounted will be disregarded by e2fsck(8) and the kernel.
        execute 'Run tune2fs' do
            command "tune2fs -i 0 -c 0 /dev/#{val_hash['vg_name']}/#{lv_name}"
            action :nothing
        end

        # Create the directory where the logical volume will be mounted. Give it a
        directory "#{val_hash['filesystem_name']}" do
            owner val_hash['owner_name']
            group val_hash['group_name']
            mode val_hash['permissions']
            recursive true
            action :create
        end

        # Mount the logical volume at the specified filesystem path and enable it to add entry to fstab.
        mount "#{val_hash['filesystem_name']}" do
            device "/dev/#{val_hash['vg_name']}/#{lv_name}"
            fstype 'ext3'
            options val_hash['options']
            dump 0
            pass 0
            action [:mount, :enable]
        end

    end
```

lv_metadata.json

```
{
    "lv_u01": {
        "vg_name": "vg_username",
        "filesystem_name": "/u01",
        "owner_name": "username",
        "group_name": "groupname",
        "permissions": 755,
        "options": "defaults",
        "sizing": "static",
        "disk_sizes": {
            "dev": {
                "small": 50,
                "medium": 50,
                "large": 50
            },
            "qa": {
                "small": 100,
                "medium": 100,
                "large": 100
            },
            "prod": {
                "small": 200,
                "medium": 200,
                "large": 200
            }
        },
        "block_size": 4096
    },
    "lv_u02": {
        "vg_name": "my_vg",
        "filesystem_name": "/u02",
        "owner_name": "username",
        "group_name": "groupname",
        "permissions": 755,
        "options": "defaults",
        "sizing": "static",
        "disk_sizes": {
            "dev": {
                "small": 5,
                "medium": 5,
                "large": 5
            },
            "qa": {
                "small": 8,
                "medium": 8,
                "large": 100
            },
            "prod": {
                "small": 10,
                "medium": 10,
                "large": 200
            }
        },
        "block_size": 4096
    },
    "lv_u03": {
        "vg_name": "my_vg",
        "filesystem_name": "/u03",
        "owner_name": "username",
        "group_name": "groupname",
        "permissions": 755,
        "options": "defaults",
        "sizing": "free",
        "disk_sizes": {
            "dev": {
                "small": 5,
                "medium": 5,
                "large": 5
            },
            "qa": {
                "small": 5,
                "medium": 5,
                "large": 5
            },
            "prod": {
                "small": 5,
                "medium": 5,
                "large": 5
            }
        },
        "block_size": 1024
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using resources with the same name, that actually do different things. You have 3 resources in the resource collection eventually with the same name: `execute 'Run tune2fs'`, but every one of them doing its own thing, because the `command "tune2fs -i 0 -c 0 /dev/#{val_hash['vg_name']}/#{lv_name}"` are different.

Chef just does not know which resource of 3, you are notifying with

`notifies :run, "execute[Run tune2fs]", :immediately`

**Use different names** for your execute resources:

```rb
lvm_logical_volume lv_name do
  group val_hash['vg_name']
  size lazy {val_hash['sizing'] == 'static' ? "#{val_hash['disk_sizes'][app_env][vm_size]}G" : "100%FREE"}
  filesystem 'ext3'
  filesystem_params lazy {lv_name == 'lv_u02' ? "-m 0 -b #{val_hash['block_size']} -J size=256" : "-m 0 -b #{val_hash['block_size']}"}
  notifies :run, "execute[Run tune2fs for #{lv_name}]", :immediately
end

# Runs tune2fs to disable time-dependent checking. 
# When setting max-mount-count to 0, the number of times the filesystem is mounted will be disregarded by e2fsck(8) and the kernel.
execute "Run tune2fs for #{lv_name}" do
  command "tune2fs -i 0 -c 0 /dev/#{val_hash['vg_name']}/#{lv_name}"
  action :nothing
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Draco! That makes sense. Not sure how I completely overlooked something so obvious. The mind works in mysterious ways.